# What does 1 day PoW mean?

Tags: altcoin-development

I see several coins advertising 1 day PoW.
An example is this coin. https://github.com/concealcoin/concealcoin

I have been studying the code but must be missing a critical part as none of the math adds to 1 day.

Can anyone shed light on this? What part of the code am I missing?

Main.cpp

```
CBigNum bnProofOfWorkLimit(~uint256(0) >> 20); // "standard" scrypt target limit for proof of work, results with 0,000244140625 proof-of-work difficulty
CBigNum bnProofOfStakeLimit(~uint256(0) >> 20);
CBigNum bnProofOfWorkLimitTestNet(~uint256(0) >> 16);

unsigned int nTargetSpacing = 1 * 30; // 30 seconds
unsigned int nStakeMinAge = 24 * 60 * 60; // 24 hours
unsigned int nStakeMaxAge = 30 * 24 * 60 * 60;           // 30 days
unsigned int nModifierInterval = 10 * 60; // time to elapse before new modifier is computed

int nCoinbaseMaturity = 80;
CBlockIndex* pindexGenesisBlock = NULL;
int nBestHeight = -1;

and the rewards from main.cpp
// miner's coin base reward
int64_t GetProofOfWorkReward(int64_t nFees)
{
    int64_t nSubsidy = 3500 * COIN;

    if (fDebug && GetBoolArg("-printcreation"))
        printf("GetProofOfWorkReward() : create=%s nSubsidy=%"PRId64"\n", FormatMoney(nSubsidy).c_str(), nSubsidy);

    return nSubsidy + nFees;
}
```

Main.h

```
static const int LAST_POW_BLOCK = 2880;

static const unsigned int MAX_BLOCK_SIZE = 1000000;
static const unsigned int MAX_BLOCK_SIZE_GEN = MAX_BLOCK_SIZE/2;
static const unsigned int MAX_BLOCK_SIGOPS = MAX_BLOCK_SIZE/50;
static const unsigned int MAX_ORPHAN_TRANSACTIONS = MAX_BLOCK_SIZE/100;
static const unsigned int MAX_INV_SZ = 50000;
static const int64_t MIN_TX_FEE = 1000;
static const int64_t MIN_RELAY_TX_FEE = MIN_TX_FEE;
static const int64_t MAX_MONEY = 17000000 * COIN;
static const int64_t COIN_YEAR_REWARD = 3 * CENT; // 3% per year
static const int64_t MAX_MINT_PROOF_OF_STAKE = 0.03 * COIN; // 3% annual interest
static const int MODIFIER_INTERVAL_SWITCH = 2000;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't have a 24-hour block time, it [issued all its PoW coins in the first 24 hours of existence](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=700289.0).

The math you're looking for is `nTargetSpacing * LAST_POW_BLOCK`, which multiplies to 86400, the number of seconds in 24 hours.

[As you can see from their home page](http://concealcoin.pw/) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Opvoa.png)), that worked out about as well as you'd expect.

Comment: ok so 30 seconds x 2880 blocks is 86400 - Thanks! I was having a brain freeze looking at all this code :)

Comment: @Joe It doesn't explicitly only allow PoW blocks for 24 hours, but it says 'make a new block about every 30 seconds, and only make 2880 blocks.'

Comment: I noticed a lot of these 1,2,3 day PoW coins usually add "approximately" 3 days POW"

Comment: @Joe yeah the idea was quickly run a POW distribution unusually secured by POS.

Comment: Bwahahaa... Hilarious answer!